# Requirements of optional stopping theorem in random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Consider the iid random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu$. Let $S_n = X_1+...+X_n$ be a random walk (it could be symmetric/unsymmetric in 1D or higher dimension, but I use the notation for 1D). We know $S_n-\mu n$ is a martingale with respect to the natural filtration. Let $T$ be a hitting time, i.e., $T=\inf\{n\ge0 : S_n = a \}$ for some $a$. I have seen in several textbooks that we can apply the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) to this martingale $M_n = S_n-\mu n$. However, I do not get why the requirements of optional stopping theorem in this case are satisfied. For example, is it true that the stopping time $T$ defined above is almost surely bounded?

*P.S. I think the hitting time is finite because random walk is recurrent. Is this true? I wonder if we can conclude that $T$ is almost surely bounded using this fact.*

Comment: You cannot apply optional stopping theorem in this case. The example you probably saw on textbooks had a stopping time of the form $T = \inf \{n\geq 0: S_n = a\mbox{ or }S_n = b\}$ where your random walk begins inside $(a,b)$. 

T cannot be almost surely bounded. Consider the symmetric random walk and suppose w.l.o.g. $a\geq 0$. For any constant $k$ you have $\{T>k\} \supseteq \{X_1 = ... = X_k = -1\}$ and $P(X_1 = ... = X_k = -1) = \frac{1}{2^k}>0.$